# Why my ViewSet keeps on looping after using for loop ang using get_object_or_404?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using [extra actions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) for my image_tags endpoint for my images. I want to POST and DELETE for each image's image_tags. I was also able to use image_id for accessing each image using `lookup_field` in my Image.

I have this endpoint for example, for an image IMG_123's image_tags:

```
localhost:8000/my_app/images/IMG_123/image_tags
```

This is my code:

```
#models.py
class ImageTag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    description = models.CharField()

class Image(models.Model):
    image_id = models.CharField(unique=True)
    image_tags = models.ManyToManyField(ImageTag, blank=True)
    ...

#serializers.py
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = '__all__'

class ImageTagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image_tags = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('image_tags',)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return data

#views.py
class ImageExtraAction(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    @action(detail=True, methods=['get', 'post', 'delete'])
    def image_tags(self, request, capture_id=None):
        print("REQ", request.data)
        capture = self.get_object()
        data = request.data.copy()

        image_tags = request.data.get('image_tags')
        print("IMG", image_tags)
        #print("LEN", len(image_tags))
        if image_tags:
            print("HERE")
            for tag in image_tags:
                obj_ = get_object_or_404(ImageTag, name=tag)
                data['image_tags'].append(obj_)

        print("DATA", data)
        serializer = ImageTagSerializer(capture, data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class ImageViewSet(ImageExtraAction, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer
    lookup_field = 'image_id'
    ...

#urls.py
router.register(r'images', ImageViewSet, basename='image')
```

When I post:

```
{"image_tags": ["Urban", "Vegetation"]}
```

I expect them to be added to image_tags field. However I am having problem since it keeps on looping at the codeblock:

```
for tag in image_tags:
    obj_ = get_object_or_404(ImageTag, name=tag)
    data['image_tags'].append(obj_)
```

Why is this happening? And how can I solve it?

I have tried debugging looking for its length, its 2 as expected but when it comes to the loop it just loops infinitely, thus my request is not fulfilled.

Comment: Have you tried with **`/my_app/images/IMG_123/image_tags/`** ? (ends with a ***slash***)

Comment: Yes. Still the same. I am actually testing it locally (not using test dev)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it loops indefinitely is because you are adding to the end of your list.

Here is your list for each iteration.

```
1. ["Urban", "Vegetation"]
2. ["Urban", "Vegetation", "Urban"]
3. ["Urban", "Vegetation", "Urban", "Vegetation"]
4. ["Urban", "Vegetation", "Urban", "Vegetation", "Urban"]
...
```

This continues with no end.

A better approach is to query all `image_tags` with one query. This also is more performant since you won't have a sperate DB query for each tag.

```py
data['image_tags'] = get_list_or_404(ImageTag, name_in=image_tags)

# or

data['image_tags'] = ImageTag.objects.filter(name_in=image_tags).all()
```

To create one if it is missing...

```py
# Query all image tags
tags = ImageTag.objects.filter(name_in=data['image_tags']).all()
# create a list of all existing tags
existing_tags = [tag.name for tag in tags]
# create a list of all tags in the request that don't exist.
missing_tags = [tag for tag in data['image_tags'] if tag not in existing_tags]
```

`missing_tags` is a list of tags that don't exist. You can simply iterate over it and create new tags.

Comment: What if one entry does not exist and I want to create for that one?

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much for answering it again.